# What variables are shared and not between processes in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
GLOBAL_VAR = 1
class Worker:
  class_var = 2
```

Worker's instances are created by multiple processes. Will they have their own copies of above variables? If not, can I use them to safely lock access to a resource accessed by multiple class instances (creating and accessing them in a thread-safe manner, of course)? I want to do it transparently for a class user. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about multithreading or multiprocessing? These are very different in Python.

Threads can access variables like you are use to in Python, without restriction.
Process on the other hand can't access variables from another process (aside some exception of shared variables). Process will copy the current state of the local variables on creation, but it will only be a copy.

Comment: Multiprocessing. Is there a way to share data without noticing a parent process?

Comment: Could you expose clearly what you are trying to achieve? There are multiple ways to communicate between processes, but it really depend on the application

Comment: There are N Worker instances each running in its own process. The parent process uses the interface which do not pass any locks/references to child workers. I do not want to change the interface, because there are other child worker species different from Worker, sharing the same interface, not needing these locks/data. Each Worker eventually access the Resource("Name"). If one workers works on "Name" others who attempt to do the same can just skip this action. So maintaining a list of Names under work shared between Workers would be enough (with one mutex for list updates, I suppose).